# Speed Up Macro Extracting Rows from Data using Column to Match

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a way to speed up this code as it takes my computer 20-30 minutes to run. It essentially runs through a list of column values in sheet "A" and if It matches a column value in sheet "B" it will pull the entire corresponding row to the sheet "Match".

```
Sub MatchSheets()
Dim lastRowAF As Integer
Dim lastRowL As Integer
Dim lastRowM As Integer
Dim foundTrue As Boolean

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastRowAF = Sheets("FHA").Cells(Sheets("FHA").Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowL = Sheets("New Construction").Cells(Sheets("New Construction").Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowM = Sheets("Match").Cells(Sheets("Match").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRowAF
foundTrue = False
For j = 1 To lastRowL

    If Sheets("FHA").Cells(i, 32).Value = Sheets("New Construction").Cells(j, 12).Value Then
        foundTrue = True
        Exit For
    End If

Next j

If foundTrue Then
    Sheets("FHA").Rows(i).Copy Destination:= _
    Sheets("Match").Rows(lastRowM + 1)
    lastRowM = lastRowM + 1
End If

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need the formatting? Or are the values good enough?  How many column on `FHA` and `New Construction`?

Comment: no I do not need formatting - 54 in FHA and 25 in New Const

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collections are optimized for looking values.  Using a combination of a Collection and Array is usually the best way to match two list. 20K Rows X 54 Columns (140K Values) took this code 10.87 seconds to copy over on a slow PC.

```
Sub NewMatchSheets()
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    Const NUM_FHA_COLUMNS As Long = 54, AF As Long = 32
    Dim list As Object
    Dim key As Variant, data() As Variant, results() As Variant
    Dim c As Long, r As Long, count As Long
    ReDim results(1 To 50000, 1 To 100)

    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New Construction")
        data = .Range("L1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "L").End(xlUp)).Value
        For Each key In data
            If key <> "" Then
                If Not list.Contains(key) Then list.Add key
            End If
        Next
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FHA")
        data = .Range(.Range("A1").Resize(1, NUM_FHA_COLUMNS), .Cells(.Rows.count, AF).End(xlUp)).Value
        For r = 1 To UBound(data)
            key = data(r, AF)
            If list.Contains(key) Then
                count = count + 1
                For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
                    results(count, c) = data(r, c)
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With

    If count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Match")
        With .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)
            .Offset(1).Resize(count, NUM_FHA_COLUMNS).Value = results
        End With
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Debug.Print Round(Timer - t, 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") is a new one to me. Previously I've used Dictionaries to do this kind of thing. Thanks for the new trick.

Comment: @jeffreyweir Dictionaries are actually a little faster. I used an ArrayList because I didn't need to store Key/Value pairs.  ArrayList  do have some keep features like Sort, Insert, Repeat, getRange.

Answer (score 1):

use variant arrays:

```
Sub MatchSheets()
Dim lastRowAF As Long
Dim lastRowL As Long
Dim lastRowM As Long


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastRowAF = Sheets("FHA").Cells(Sheets("FHA").Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowL = Sheets("New Construction").Cells(Sheets("New Construction").Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowM = Sheets("Match").Cells(Sheets("Match").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim FHAArr As Variant
    FHAArr = Sheets("FHA").Range(Sheets("FHA").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("FHA").Cells(lastRowAF, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value

Dim NewConArr As Variant
    NewConArr = Sheets("New Construction").Range(Sheets("New Construction").Cells(1, 12), Sheets("New Construction").Cells(lastRowL, 12)).Value

Dim outarr As Variant
ReDim outarr(1 To UBound(FHAArr, 1), 1 To UBound(FHAArr, 2))

Dim k As Long
k = 0
Dim l As Long

For i = 1 To lastRowAF
    For j = 1 To lastRowL
        If FHAArr(i, 32) = NewConArr(j, 1) Then
            For l = 1 To UBound(FHAArr, 2)
                k = k + 1
                outarr(k, l) = FHAArr(i, l)
            Next l
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Sheets("Match").Cells(lastRowM + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(outarr, 1), UBound(outarr, 2)).Value = outarr

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>FHA Worksheet: 2500 rows by 50 columns
> New Construction Worksheet: 500 rows by 1 column L
> Match Worksheet: 450 transfers from FMA</sub>
>  
> Elapsed time: **[0.13 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51198525/speed-up-macro-extracting-rows-from-data-using-column-to-match/51199780#51199780)**

Get rid of all the nested loop and work with arrays.

Your narrative seemed to suggest that there might be multiple matches for any one value but your code only looks for a single match then Exit For. I'll work with the latter of the two scenarios.

```
Sub MatchSheets()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim vFM As Variant, vNC As Variant

    Debug.Print Timer

    With Worksheets("New Construction")
        vNC = .Range(.Cells(1, "L"), _
                     .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With

    With Worksheets("FHA")
        vFM = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), _
                     .Cells(.Rows.Count, _
                            .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With

    ReDim vM(LBound(vFM, 2) To UBound(vFM, 2), 1 To 1)

    For i = LBound(vFM, 1) To UBound(vFM, 1)
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(vFM(i, 32), vNC, 0)) Then
            For j = LBound(vFM, 2) To UBound(vFM, 2)
                vM(j, UBound(vM, 2)) = vFM(i, j)
            Next j
            ReDim Preserve vM(LBound(vFM, 2) To UBound(vFM, 2), LBound(vM, 2) To UBound(vM, 2) + 1)
        End If
    Next i

    With Worksheets("match")
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(vM, 2), UBound(vM, 1)) = _
            Application.Transpose(vM)
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print Timer

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice work on the header.  Good time too.  I didn't even have to look,  I knew you used `Application.Match()`.  I suck at Worksheet Formula. +1

Comment: Well, you took the dictionary route so an inverse array was the best method left.

Comment: @TinMan - Bet the OP had to blink twice to realize your routine was actually finished when it did.

Comment: Lol thats how I feel when I kick the kids off the gaming computer to run tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
Sheets("FHA").Rows(i).Copy Destination:= _
Sheets("Match").Rows(lastRowM + 1)
```

For the following line:

```
Sheets("Match").Rows(lastRowM + 1).Value for Sheets("FHA").Rows(i).value
```

If you really need to shave milliseconds, you could also set: `lastRowM` to be:

```
lastRowM = Sheets("Match").Cells(Sheets("Match").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

And use:

```
Sheets("Match").Rows(lastRowM).Value for Sheets("FHA").Rows(i).value
```

Thus saving you an addition every time you go through that part of the code

Comment: I've never seen the For keyword used like that. It's a bit confusing being in a code block like that.

Comment: It's either that or `Change.... To:` <g> I edited the post to make it less confusing.